# change cursor immediately after keyup

Tags: javascript

I have this sample code on a wordpress plugin page I am implementing:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('body').toggleClass('waiting');
        sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

the matter is once I press ESCAPE key the page fires the toggle AFTER 5 seconds or after calling a function like InitPanel();... it seems effectively changes cursor after exiting the keyup function... 
Is there a trick to force INSIDE the keyup and BEFORE starting time sleep counting ?

Thanks, 
Cheers
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `sleep()` function is, so I don't know how it's stopping the page but if you put a slight delay before that it should solve your problem...

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('body').toggleClass('waiting');
        setInterval(function() {
            sleep(5000);
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Quite often, if you make DOM changes then a slight delay is required in order to allow the page to refresh and show those pages.

Comment: that sleep(5000) is basically a for() counting from Date() each milliseconds

Comment: that sleep(5000) is basically a for() counting from Date() each milliseconds and really I have another function that re-initiates some fields but I wanted to show first a progress cursor then calling re-initiate funcion then show default cursor.. but my tests using addClass() and removeClass() haven't produced results and using toggleClass() showed progress cursor only after it exited from $(document).keyup function